# Melting/smoking universal AC adapter

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

I own a Samsung RV520 for 2 years now and 3 months ago my AC adapter stopped working and had to replaced. I went to the closest computer service and they gave me an universal AC adapter. Now, the new AC adapter worked like a charm, but only for 2 weeks.

It was just an average work day and I plugged in my AC adapter and started working.

After 2 hours I smelled something funny I didn't know what it was, I ignored it and went back home.

The next day I smelled it again and I found out that the plug from the adapter was smoking and really hot. I disconnected it and found that the tip (yellow plastic ring) completely melted *inside* my laptop.

Ever since I plug it in, it would start smoking the very second I connected it.

So obviously I need a replacement.

Just found out that my laptop’s old AC adapter used 60 watt and this one 90 watt, even though the guys at the service said it was fine.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes; Use a proper adapter but clearly the connector on the laptop is damaged and will require repair.

Answer (score 3):

You used an adapter which gave half again as much power as your laptop likely can handle. As you noticed yourself, your connector has been fried.

However, it's is possible that some internal components of your laptop and/or battery have been damaged as well. If this is the case, you likely need to replace it or at least turn it in for repair. Because you used unsupported peripherals, it's likely that your warranty won't cover this (if your warranty was still valid to begin with).

I don't think it's possible to prevent something which already happened.

What you should do now first is get a backup of the essential data on the laptop. You don't know if the internal components are fine, so it might fail at any moment. Then you need to turn in your laptop for repair. Your connector needs replacement and any further use will reduce the lifespan of the rest of the device.

And of course, you need a new AC adapter.

Comment: Sure its possible to avoid something like this in the future, use the proper adapter, but as you point not much you can do currently until its repaired.

Comment: A power supply doesn't "push" power. It provides. Just because it *can* provide more, doesn't mean the connected devices actually uses it. It's simple, really: `I = U / R`. The only thing that *does* matter is the output voltage.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases like this it is not the wattage, but the quality and the connection, or possibly the voltage. It would be more rare that an adapter of an increased amperage causes this kind of problems.

There is also the high possibility that the reason the first one burned out was the battery is going out .  It is like when a fuse pops on you, without determining why the fuse popped , putting in another might not be the best way.
When the first adapter burned out, I would want to know why.  Power supplys can get weaker and more dirty power over time, and all of todays cheaper stuff does fail sooner and more often.  So you cannot Know anything for a fact, but it might be time then to do a discovery.

I am suggesting that the device be checked out way better, specifically for the battery. Because now the power jack inlet location will at least have to be checked also, the device should be generally checked out much better . . . to prevent this.